# Javascript stop form submittion

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, form-submit

I'm using this event listener to for the submit buttons:

```
document.forms[formID].addEventListener('submit',validate);
```

I want to make the page stay as it is when submitting without refreshing or redirecting,
this is the `validate` function, and the `return false;` doesn't work

```
function validate() {

    CheckedN = this.name;
    CorrectAnswer = questions.correctAns[CheckedN];
    UserAnswer = -1;

    for (var i=0; i < 4; i++) {
        if (this.answerN[i].checked === true) {
            UserAnswer = i;
        }
    }

    if (UserAnswer === -1) {alert("Please choose an answer");}
    else {
        if (UserAnswer === CorrectAnswer) {alert("You are correct!");}
        else {alert("You are wrong!");}
        }

return false;
}
```

what am I doing wrong?
thanx

Comment: validate function always return false you need to return true in your valid case

Comment: Since you've said you're using jQuery (even though you're not using it in the quoted code), I've added the `jquery` tag for you to let people know that jQuery-specific answers are okay.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you can use jquery, you can use:

```
event.preventDefault()
```

Like:

```
$("#formId").submit(function(event) {
...
  event.preventDefault();
...
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/

Comment: He didn't say he was using jQuery (and is pretty clearly *not* doing so). Please don't answer JavaScript questions with jQuery-only answers.

Comment: Topera clearly said "If you can use jquery". Topera's answer is fine.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder I do use jQuery and this answer was quite helpful, also I don't see any reason anyone would avoid using it...

Comment: @IlyaD: If you're using jQuery, best to tag the question appropriately. (And to use jQuery for hooking things up!) I've updated my answer to include the jQuery-specific stuff.

Comment: @IlyaD: No. When you call `event.preventDefault();` you're stopping the default action of the event. So, the form will not be submitted.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder: Sorry, but I think you're inconsistent. First you said: `No, let's not go back to 1996`...a then said `Please don't answer JavaScript questions with jQuery-only answers`. I'm using the answer do teach people using "new" technologies. That's why I answered a jquery answer.

Comment: @Topera: No inconsistency at all. You don't have to use a library to not be coding in 1996. (There's this whole DOM2 events spec [and Microsoft's proprietary equivalents] to use.) But when there's no indication (as there wasn't in this case) that someone is using one specific library, an answer that only uses that library is not useful. Answer the question asked. You can always include an addendum saying "But really, use a library for this."

Comment: @T.J. Crowder: Ok. I'll think about this.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder: Thanks for explanation to @IlyaD

Comment: @T.J. Crowder Thanx for the expalnation

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**: You've said in a comment elsewhere that you're using jQuery. That's surprising because your code isn't using it to hook up the event handler.

If you're using jQuery, this gets a lot simpler (as I mentioned below in the "off-topic" bit).

Hook it up like this:

```
$(document.forms[formID]).submit(validate);
```

And change your `validate` function to accept an `event` parameter and call `preventDefault` on it:

```
function validate(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    // ...rest of function here
}
```

jQuery smooths over all of the issues listed below.

---

**Original answer**:

Some things to change (but see also the off-topic note at the very end):

1. Your `addEventListener` call is missing a parameter, it should be:

   ```
   document.forms[formID].addEventListener('submit',validate,false);
   //                                                        ^--- required
   ```
2. Your `validate` function will receive an `event` object (on standards-compliant browsers). It should have a `preventDefault` function on it, which when called stops the default action of the browser (submitting the form). So declare the argument and call the function on it if it's there.
3. Sadly, to support IE you have to use `attachEvent` rather than `addEventListener` (which they only started supporting in IE9).
4. And also sadly, to support IE you have to handle the fact that they treat the event object as a global rather than passing it in.
5. **AND** there may not be a `preventDefault` function on it. *sigh*

So all told, hookup:

```
var form = document.forms[formID];
if (form.addEventListener) {
    // Standards
    form.addEventListener('submit',validate,false);
}
else if (form.attachEvent) {
    // IE
    form.attachEvent('onsubmit', validate); // No third parameter, note the "on"
}
else {
    // REALLY old browser
    form.onsubmit = validate;
}
```

Then the function:

```
function validate(event) {
    var valid;

    event = event || window.event; // Handle IE difference

    CheckedN = this.name;
    CorrectAnswer = questions.correctAns[CheckedN];
    UserAnswer = -1;

    for (var i=0; i < 4; i++) {
        if (this.answerN[i].checked === true) {
            UserAnswer = i;
        }
    }

    if (UserAnswer === -1) {
        alert("Please choose an answer");
    }
    else {
        if (UserAnswer === CorrectAnswer) {
            alert("You are correct!");
        }
        else {
            alert("You are wrong!");
        }
    }

    // Both preventDefault and return false, to cover various browser
    if (event.preventDefault) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
    return false;
}
```

---

**Off-topic**: As you can see, there are a lot of browser inconsistencies that you have to deal with there. Rather than doing it yourself, I recommend using a library like [jQuery](http://jquery.com), [Prototype](http://prototypejs.org), [YUI](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/), [Closure](http://code.google.com/closure/library), or [any of several others](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_JavaScript_libraries) to smooth over those inconsistencies for you (and also provide a lot of other handy utility stuff) so you can concentrate on what you're actually trying to do without sweating the small stuff.

Comment: Thanx for the detailed explanation, I think i am going to switch to jquery.

Comment: @IlyaD: It's a great library. :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById(formId).onsubmit = validate;
```

Or even simpler, in your page markup, do:

```
<form id="myFormId" onsubmit="return validate();">
    <!-- Form content here -->
</form>
```

Comment: No, let's **not** go back to 1996.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder  - Meh.  We go back to what is the most simple solution that works in all major browsers.  Preventing a form's default behavior by returning `false` from its `onSubmit()` function has been around for a long time, works, and is quite a bit simpler than the answer you provided.

Comment: It also tightly couples the code and (in the case of your second suggestion) intermingles code and markup. That's fine in someone's garage; in a large organization with dedicated designers and dedicated coders, not so much. It's unnecesary and limiting.

Comment: Oh year let's try and get addeventlistener and attachevent to work cross browser when what Aroth posted works in all browsers I have ever seen and used. Only thing I would change is to add it in a window.onload and use document.forms[0].onsubmit=validate; It is called being pragmatic.

Answer (score 0):

This is off the top of my head but I think the html control that submits the form should be something like this:

```
<input type="submit" value="submit this form" onclick="return validate()"/>
```

Comment: Never do validation on the click of submit button when you can do it in onsubmit of the form

Answer (score 0):

This would work in all browsers using plain JS. Let the downvote fest begin

http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/zUFEw/

```
window.onload=function() {
  document.forms[0].onsubmit=validate; 
}

function validate() {
  var CheckedN = this.name;
  var CorrectAnswer = questions.correctAns[CheckedN];
  var UserAnswer = -1;
  for (var i=0, n=this.answerN.length; i < n; i++) {
    if (this.answerN[i].checked) {
      UserAnswer = i;
      break; // assuming only one answer
    }
  }

  if (UserAnswer === -1) {alert("Please choose an answer");}
  else {
    if (UserAnswer === CorrectAnswer) {alert("You are correct!");}
    else {alert("You are wrong!");}
  }
  return false; // will always stop submission unless there is an error above
}
```

PS: NEVER call anything in a form for name="submit" or id="submit"

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
document.forms[formID].addEventListener('submit', function(event)
{
     event.preventDefault();
     CheckedN = this.name;
    CorrectAnswer = questions.correctAns[CheckedN];
    UserAnswer = -1;

    for (var i=0; i < 4; i++) {
        if (this.answerN[i].checked === true) {
            UserAnswer = i;
        }
    }

    if (UserAnswer === -1) {alert("Please choose an answer");}
    else {
        if (UserAnswer === CorrectAnswer) {alert("You are correct!");}
        else {alert("You are wrong!");}
        }

return false;

}, false);
```

Alternatively, you may try to just change the `validate()` to `validate(event)` and call  `event.preventDefault();` in there, but I'm not 100% on that.

Comment: Why take a perfectly good named function and make it anonymous? Having functions have names helps your tools help you (by showing them in call stacks, etc.).